# Trying to create a drop-down of form fields, that is based on a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, contact-form-7, input-field

Good afternoon!
I am building a contact form in Contact Form 7 in Wordpress. And I need a functionality where one of the form fields is a number selector (for example, 1-10) and I need the number that is selected to be calculated and drop down the number of fields to be inputted.

I'll try to explain the best I can. So if someone types in the 4...I need a drop down of four input fields.

I have looked for some jquery script for this functionality, but I'm basically at a deadend. If anyone has any suggestions, I would much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option using jQuery ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrismborland/vFCsL/))

#### HTML

```
Number of inputs:
<select class="numInputs" onChange="buildInputs(this);">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div class="inputs"></div>
```

#### Javascript (jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // set onchange event for the select box.
    $('.numInputs').change(function () {
        // clear any inputs added to the div.
        $('.inputs').empty();
        // get number of inputs to add from select box.
        var num = $('.numInputs option:selected').text();
        // build the inputs.
        for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            $('<input type="text"/><br/>').appendTo('.inputs');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the feedback. You're solution is what I'm looking for. I plugged your script in, but it still won't populate the fields when you choose a number. I saw that it worked in Jsfiddle. I think it has to do with the shortcodes that are used in Contact Form 7. Any suggestions?

Comment: @toolbox3 have you tried debugging this issue in the browser?  It appears that you're getting an exception:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: buildInputs is not defined (toolboxwebdesign.com/:318)` on line 318 of the source.  Where did you define the `buildInputs` method from my example?

Comment: Oh, I have two headers that I use. Okay, now the script is in the <head> still nothing? Is there another thing that I am missing?

Comment: Your closing `<script>` tag is missing the forward slash `/`, it should be `</script>`.  Also, you should probably combine all of your `$(document).ready(....);` calls at some point (although it's not necessary for it to work).

Comment: I accepted it. However, I tried into a different site and it didn't work. I wonder if there is some sort of conflict. could you please look at my code? http://lawofficeelizabethvhan.com/contact/

Comment: You need to move the javascript further down on the page.  It hasn't loaded the jQuery script yet when you first reference `$`.

Comment: Still not working on that site. I'm thinking it might be the particular Wordpress theme that I'm using...

Comment: Try changing `$(document).ready(function() {` to `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {`

Comment: that made the function worked, but there were like 10 input fields, when I selected just 1. Hmmm....

Comment: Nope, nevermind...figured it out. Thanks alot for your patience Chris!

Answer (score 0):

You would use javascript, I wrote a simple sample for you. I haven't ever worked with wordpress, but this just works on it's own, and I would think you should be able to just put it in.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function thing(){
        var num = document.getElementById("number").value; //Get the number out of the number field
        document.getElementById("select").innerHTML = ''; //Get rid of the placeholder, or the old ones
        for (var i = 0; i < num; i++){
            var newOpt = document.createElement('option');
            newOpt.innerHTML = i; //It'll just have a dropdown for 0 to the number
            newOpt.value = i;
            document.getElementById("select").appendChild(newOpt);
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form>
    Number: <input type="number" name="number" id="number" onblur="thing();">
    <select id="select">
        <option value="no">Enter a number first</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Also, instead of using onblur, you could use onkeyup or something. onblur is for when it loses focus.

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, I was looking for more what Chris put below.